Camel route testing - delete all steps starting with the selected one
I have a problem with adjusting the Camel route on the need of tests.
I have following route defined:
from(source)
            .routeId(ROUTE_GENERAL_ID)
            .wireTap(inputMetrics)
            .to(mappingStep)
            .process(enrichingWithInternalData)
            .process(enrichingWithExternalData)

I want to test the route which ends with the wiretap. So there is no need to perform processing of the steps from the "main" route. These ones mentioned below:
            .to(mappingStep)
            .process(enrichingWithInternalData)
            .process(enrichingWithExternalData)

If there is no need to run them, I want to remove them to not waste time on the executing them. I was able to remove them, but I could only accomplish it by removing them one by one using adviceWith.
 adviceWith(context, ROUTE_GENERAL_ID, builder -> builder.weaveByToUri("mappingStep").remove())
 adviceWith(context, ROUTE_GENERAL_ID, builder -> builder.weaveByToUri("enrichingWithInternalData").remove())
 adviceWith(context, ROUTE_GENERAL_ID, builder -> builder.weaveByToUri("enrichingWithExternalData").remove())

But this solution requires to modify test, when any step will be added/removed to main path. Another idea is to manually iterate over the route. But I'm curious, if there is something already in camel, which I can use here. Or maybe you know more smooth solution for it.

You can divide your original route, for example like this:
from(source)
  .routeId(ROUTE_GENERAL_ID)
  .wireTap(inputMetrics)
  .to("direct:mappingStep");

from("direct:mappinStep")
  .routeId("mappingStep")
  .process(enrichingWithInternalData)
  .process(enrichingWithExternalData);

Now you can skip the routing to the direct:mappingStep endpoint in your test like follows. Also don't forget to tell your test, you're using AdviceWith:
...
@Override
public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    return true;
}

@Test
public void testRoute() throws Exception {
  adviceWith(context, ROUTE_GENERAL_ID, builder -> builder.weaveByToUri("mappingStep").remove())

  ...
}


Thanks, I thought that maybe camel api gives such a possibility. But it seems that we need to take care of our own. And yes, this solution looks as clean as it possible.
